# Google App Engine saving toString() value, not Text

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a problem with the Google App Engine and datastorage.

When I try to save a newly created Text instance with the DataStore, it only saves the representation of toString() of that Text.

```
Text myText = new Text("This is a test");
entity.setProperty("value", myText);
datastore.put(entity);
```

This results in the value:

"value" : "< Text: This is a test >"

which is exactly the toString()-representation of my Text-object. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks for you help,
Jan Scheele

PS: I also tried setUnindexedProperty(...) with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are reading the value you have to use getValue -method in the Text -instance.

```
return ((Text) entity.getProperty("value")).getValue();
```

Comment: I'm not reading the value, I'm looking into the database. Or is the page smart enough to show the shortend version there too?

Comment: You were right! The value was stored correctly, but the _ah/admin page displayed a shortend version! Thank you!